# How does Libsodium send more than one encrypted message?

Tags: php, libsodium

I'm using sodium_crypto_box() to send encrypted data between two web servers. I have both servers set up and successfully creating public and private keys, but I'm a little confused.

The proper way to do it is to generate the public and private keys just one time. Then I store the private keys in a safe place and use the public key of each server to submit data back and forth each time I need to exchange data, correct?

If that's correct, then it's the nonce that I'm confused about. I know it is only to be used once for obvious reasons, but does that mean it's only generated once or only *used* once. In other words, do I generate a new nonce for every single exchange of data between servers A & B, or just generate the nonce one time and use it along with the public key?

Comment: You use nonce to encrypt, and you use it ONCE. To decrypt, you need the same nonce. It's used once per encrypt/decrypt dance. Every time you use `sodium_crypto_box`, you'd create a new random string (nonce). However, since you're sending data between two servers - why not use TLS and then you don't need to do encryption on your own?

Comment: I'm trying to store the data encrypted at rest. I suppose I could unencrypted and then send it over the internet with TLS, but it's 6 of one or half a dozen of another in this case.

Sounds like the nonce is just like a second private key, but I'm using the nonce one time with every transmission of data, so 1,000 messages sent = 1,000 generated nonces, one for each message.